# move between module in android studio?

Tags: android, module

I want to go a module when click on a menu item in my program but it has an error.

It's error comes:

```
can not resolve constructor Intent(com.ichi2.anki.DeckPicker,java.lang.Class<com.ichi2.anki.alarmmanager.AlarmMngr>).
```

this is my code but i don't know how to solve it:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.alarm:{
        Timber.i("DeckPicker:: alarm button pressed");
        startActivity(new Intent(this,com.ichi2.anki.alarmmanager.AlarmMngr.class));
        return true;}
```

Comment: use just `startActivity(new Intent(this, AlarmMngr.class));`

Comment: @W4R10CK i tried it but it didn't.

Comment: Which class is this constructor being called in? An `Activity`?

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed yes DeckPicker is an activity

Comment: `new Intent(this, AlarmMngr.class)` might not have worked because you must be making this call from another subclass of `DeckPicker`... like an `View.OnClickListener` or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the official documentation to find the available constructors for `Intent` here: [Public Constructors | Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#pubctors)

The constructor you are probably trying to call here is:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

The right way of calling it would be:

```
new Intent(DeckPicker.this, AlarmMngr.class)
```

---

The `switch case` you have mentioned there needs a correction too, you can change it to:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.alarm:
        Timber.i("DeckPicker:: alarm button pressed");
        startActivity(new Intent(DeckPicker.this, AlarmMngr.class));
        return true;
}
```

The case does not require a curly brace enclosure - `{}`